# ssh config with dynamic IP

Tags: ssh

I have a EC2 instance with a dynamic IP and I would like to connect to it directly without having to modify the `.ssh/config` every time it changes.

I can query the ip with

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters 'Name=tag:Name,Values=MYTAG' --query 'Reservations[0].Instances[0].NetworkInterfaces[0].Association.PublicIp' --output text
```

Now, I want to add this command to the `ProxyCommand` section in my `.ssh/config` file but I'm getting some errors.

This is the section for that host

```
Host ec2-instance
     User ubuntu
     IdentityFile my/pem/file.pem
     ProxyCommand bash -c "host=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --filters 'Name=tag:Name,Values=MYTAG' --query 'Reservations[0].Instances[0].NetworkInterfaces[0].Association.PublicIp' --output text); ssh ${host}"
```

I honestly don't know how the `ProxyCommand` option works and neither `man ssh` or `man ssh_config` seems to do a good job explaining it.

can this be achieved?

Comment: yes, I deleted my comment because I read it too fast :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ProxyCommand acts as an alternative for the *raw TCP connection.* It doesn't replace the whole SSH connection – although you often see it used to invoke `ssh -W`, but that's still just using another SSH system to provide a raw TCP tunnel.

So in your situation, the ProxyCommand should run some simple "TCP pipe" app such as `nc` or `socat` or `ncat` – anything which attaches stdin/stdout to a TCP connection will do:

```
Host ...
    ProxyCommand bash -c "host=...; nc $host %p"

Host ...
    ProxyCommand bash -c "host=...; socat STDIO TCP:$host:%p"
```

I would really recommend moving all the complex stuff out of your ~/.ssh/config into a separate script, so that your configuration could just look like this:

```
Host ...
    ProxyCommand ~/bin/ec2-connect %h %p
```

Comment: Because the command is executed using the user's shell `exec` directive, at some point it's `exec bash -c "… $host …"` *in some shell*. Therefore `$host` will be expanded at this stage (i.e. prematurely). Additional or different quoting/escaping can prevent it. Moving the code to a separate script is a very good way to avoid such pitfalls, so +1 for the answer anyway.

Comment: I ended up doing the "separate file + nc connection" way. Thanks, it's working